# Make fadeIn from black css

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transitions, fade

I've been using keyframes and animations to make my section fade in, but whenever I use opacity, it always fades in from *white*. How do I make it so my screen starts off as black and fades in to stuff in my section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a black overlay to your element (using an element of same size with `position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;` while either the original element is the parent of the overlay with `position: relative` or their common parent element has `position: relative`) and fade / transition the opacity value for the overlay the other way round - from 1.0 to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the overlay as specified by `@Johannes`:

> "Create a black overlay to your element"

```
.overlay-black{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    z-index:1;
    background-color:black;
    animation-name:fadeIn;
    animation-duration:0.5s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to{
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```